# Using the formula px = dp * (dpi/160) for creating image resources does not result in sharp images

Tags: android, android-imageview

Although this question is not related to programming, it is related to app development.

Suppose I have an ImageView whose dimensions are 40dp*40dp. If I use the above formula to create an icon for a device with screen density 217 ppi, the size of the icon that fits the ImageView exactly is 55px*55px. If I use this icon in the view in consideration, the result is that the icon does not appear very sharp.

On the other hand, if I use a larger image of size, say 80px*80px, it appears sharp. So this larger image is larger than the exactly fitting one by a factor of 1.6.

What I would like to know is whether there is a certain value of the above factor that is most efficient and conventional. I would like to follow conventions while developing my apps.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How are you resizing? Also keep in mind that resizing will never be as good as creating the graphics the right size to start with.

Comment: which drawable folder you use for this image ?

Comment: I export bitmap from a vector graphics editor (Inkscape), so there is no problem of resizing.

Comment: @JafarKhQ Right now, I'm testing on only 1 device so I use the main drawable folder.

Comment: @DavidHeisnam you can use the loading bitmap sample from developer [page](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: @Glenn-- I'm setting the image through XML. The page is helpful while setting bitmaps programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ImageView` size is 40dp, thats equal to:

1. 40 x 1.0 = 40  pixel on mdpi devices
2. 40 x 1.5 = 60  pixel on hdpi devices
3. 40 x 2.0 = 80  pixel on xhdpi devices
4. 40 x 3.0 = 120 pixel on xxhdpi devices
5. 40 x 4.0 = 160 pixel on xxxhdpi devices

Now your device is `hdpi` (217). for thats device you need a 60x60 pixel bitmap, and you have to put it in the `drawable-hdpi` directory.

Using `drawable` directory is like using `drawable-mdpi` directory. fro each resource in that directory android will scale it up/down before using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw that page just before posting this question but misinterpreted it. And I saw no difference when I moved the images to drawable-hdpi folder, although I know it is good practice to use the appropriate folder.